# Does an outright incorrect answer denote "low quality"?

Tags: discussion, closing, answers

An answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229927/ethan-the-wise-extended) came up in the low quality posts review. Just having posted an answer here seems to be a bad idea, as the question itself is on hold.

That said, I could not find anything wrong with it. I found [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/does-length-of-answer-necessarily-denote-low-quality/8314#8314), suggesting it may have been flagged automatically, due to its length.

However, the question itself is an identification question. A poorly written, off-topic one (thus the 'on hold'), but the original asker has been able to confirm that the answer was not correct.

**If an answer is undeniable incorrect, does this count as being 'low quality'? If not, is there any particular action we should take, or should it be left up to the community to down vote?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't count as being low quality. In fact there is a flag decline reason that states that flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer.

Downvote it, comment on how it is incorrect, etc, but don't flag it as very low quality.

That flag should really only be used in the rare cases where some good old fashioned editing wouldn't save a post and it is just garbage gibberish. If you can edit it to look even reasonably good, then use those skills. VLQ should only be used if everything is completely hopeless and cannot be massaged into decentish understandable content (regardless of correctness).

Comment: Feel free, however, to flag wrong answers that are malicious, trolling, irrelevant  or explicitly harmful. However, it's best to use a custom flag **explaining** this, because a simple NaA flag will often result in little more than a skim and delete or decline.